# Two Dimensional Array of Structures in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create two dimensional array in javascript where each cell is a structure with properties. How can I access the properties of the cell structure?

### This is my code:

```
// function to create cell objects
function cell () {
  return {
    "value" : 0,
    "open" : 0,
    "mine" : false
  };
};

// initialise all cells
var game = new Array(10);

for(var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
  game[i] = new Array(10);

  for(var j = 0 ; j < 10; j++){
   game[i][j] = cell();
  }
}
```

How can I access the properties?

I've tried different commands and I get undefined property.

```
game[0][0]["mine"] = true;
game[0][0].mine = true;
```

Thanks.

---- UPDATE ----
I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'mine' of undefined (line 38)
```

### This is my exact code

```
// Minesweeper game

// ask user to the size of game
var rows = Number(prompt("Please enter number of rows", "10"));
var cols = Number(prompt("Please enter number of columns", "10"));

// calculate number of mines
var mines = Math.floor(rows*cols*0.2);

// function to create cell objects
function cell (value, open) {
    return {
      "value" : value,
      "open" : open,
      "mine" : false
    };
};

// initialise all cells
var game = new Array(rows);

for(var i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++){
  game[i] = new Array(cols);

  for(var j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++){
    game[i][j] = cell(0, false);
  }
}

// place mines randomly
for(var i = 0 ; i < mines ; i++){
  var placedMine = false;
  while(!placedMine){
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random()*rows)); 
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random()*cols));

    if( game[i][j].mine === false){
      game[i][j].mine = true;
      placedMine = true;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Your code sample works exactly the way you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the array itself, but with the last if statement in your code

```
  if( game[i][j].mine === false){
    game[i][j].mine = true;
    placedMine = true;
  }
```

j is defined and used in a for loop previously. That for loop exits when `j` is equals `cols` and j keeps the value (the value of `cols`) so the condition in the if statement is equal to

```
  if( game[0][cols].mine === false){
     ...
  }
```

and since you have never assigned anything to `game[0][cols]` that expression (`game[0][cols]`) is undefined and have no property called `mine`

you also have a functional bug. You  are using i in the last for loop as a counter for mines as well as the row number. What I think you actually want to do is this

```
// place mines randomly
for(var i = 0 ; i < mines ; i++){
  var placedMine = false;
  while(!placedMine){
    var row = Math.floor((Math.random()*rows)),
        col = Math.floor((Math.random()*cols)),
        cell = game[row][cell];

    if(cell.mine === false){
      cell.mine = true;
      placedMine = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I've made three changes:

1. I've given `x`and `y` more descriptive names
2. I've declared a new variable called `cell`
3. I've used `row` and `col` (formerly `x` and `y`) as indexes instead of `i`and `j`

By creating a variable to hold the cell reference you removed the need for indexing twice and renaming x and y makes the code easier to read (especially since x is usually the horizontal value aka the column number and y is usually the vertical value)

Comment: Oh gosh! How did I miss that! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Update: I have no idea why my answer was downvoted since this was posted before OP posted the update, but whatever.

I just did this:

```
            // function to create cell objects
            function cell() {
                return {
                    "value": 0,
                        "open": 0,
                        "mine": false
                };
            };

            // initialise all cells
            var game = new Array(10);

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                game[i] = new Array(10);

                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    game[i][j] = cell();
                }
            }
            console.log(game[0][0].mine);
```

and I get the value properly on my console. What exactly is the problem with accessing it?